# How to have one pthread continue while another thread is waiting on a semaphore in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I am currently going over an example our professor gave us before our current assignment with semaphores and pthreading in C++. Currently, the entire program waits when one of the threads is blocked.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int account = 99;
bool sent = false;
int rate = 12;
int hours = 15;
sem_t s1;
sem_t s2;


//work thread
void *work(void*){
  while(1){
      sem_wait(&s1);
      account += hours * rate;
      cout << "Account: " << account << endl;
      if(account >= 1000 && !sent){
          sem_post(&s2);
          sent = true;
      }
      sem_post(&s1);

      pthread_exit(NULL);
  }
}

void* buy(void*){
  while(1){
      sem_wait(&s2);
      sem_wait(&s1);
      account -= 1000;
      sent = false;
      cout << "iPhone bought!! Account: " << account << endl;
      sem_post(&s1);
      pthread_exit(NULL);
  }
}

int main(){

  pthread_t workt, buyt;
    sem_init(&s1, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&s2, 0, 0);

  while(1){
    pthread_create( &workt, NULL, work, NULL);
    pthread_create( &buyt, NULL, buy, NULL);

    pthread_join(workt, NULL);
    pthread_join(buyt, NULL);
  }
    sem_close(&s1);
    sem_close(&s2);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The program should run the 'work' thread continuously until enough is in the account (1000), then it will buy an iPhone. My code will run until it hits the sem_wait(s2) semaphore in the 'buy' thread, which blocks the thread as it should, but my entire program waits and does not run the 'work' thread again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `pthread_exit(NULL);` on every iteration through your loop in `work`.  Basically it's acting like there's no loop.

Maybe you mean something more like:

```
  while(!sent){
      sem_wait(&s1);
      account += hours * rate;
      cout << "Account: " << account << endl;
      if(account >= 1000){
          sem_post(&s2);
          sent = true;
      }
      sem_post(&s1);

  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
```

Comment: That does get it to work. Thank you!! I may be misunderstanding him too, but would there be a way to have ```work``` continue creating and executing threads while ```buy``` is waiting?

Comment: @cspear work isn't ever going to create a thread - it is a thread that is created once.   The while(1) is what makes it keep doing "work" to add "money" to the account.

Comment: True. I suppose if I wanted to implement what I am saying, I would need different loops and logic in my ```main()``` around the ```pthread_create``` initializations. Thanks again!

Comment: @cspear yes, that sounds like the approach to create multiple threads to run the `work` function